# View Composer Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

I´m trying to pass some values in a web so I create `View Composer`, but returns 'Undefined variable'. I add this code in provider

```
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
   public function boot()
   {
   View::composer(['front.index'],'App\Http\ViewComposers\AsideComposer');
   }
```

In `AsideComposer` I add

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use App\Category;
use App\Tag;
class AsideComposer{
  public function compose(View $view)
  {
   $categories=Category::all();
   $tags=Tag::all();
   $view->with('categories', $categories)->with('tags', $tags);
  }
}
```

Index return `Undefined variable:categories`. Any idea?

Comment: Is the `boot()` method in your AppServiceProvider?

Answer (score 1):

Then in your config/app.php in the 'providers' array add:

```
App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. While returning the variable to the view, try using `compact()` like :

```
$view->with( compact('variable1', 'variable2') );
```

This fixed the error for me.